# Numeric Range Validation

Tags: handsontable

I am new to handsontable.  I am trying to validate a numeric cell with numbers between 1 and 121.  I am not sure how to go about this, any helpe would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I seem to get faster, better, and more answers when I [include just a little snippet of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). probably because it is much easier for others to copy/paste/modify rather than writing an example from scratch, and programmers can more generally read the code to quickly see the problem regardless of what language the question was written in.

Answer (score 0):

In handsontable, you can create [custom validators](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.24.3/demo-data-validation.html) for your columns. Whether that is a function or a simple regex, you can set that to a variable and then pass it as the validator to your column.

```
var specificNumberValidator = // Maybe a regex function to check for only numbers 1-121 here?

hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    ...
    columns: [
      {
        data: 'specificNumber',
        type: 'numeric',
        validator: specificNumberValidator
      }
    ]
  });
```